# What is the best way to convert a string to time in php?

Tags: php, string, datetime

I have a MySQL table containing date and time in one of its column as text (15/05/2018 11:05:40). I want to convert this string to DateTime format so that it can be used to fetch data based on the date in PHP.

Comment: `DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )` [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $time);
```